# Declaring a c# list inside method

Tags: c#, list, fortran, declaration, fortran77

I am trying to replicate the fortran 77 code to C#.
This is the line that is causing the trouble (at least I think):

```
real acl,c(0:10)
```

How would I declare this new `c` list under some method in C#?
Like this:

```
float acl;
float[] c = new float[0:10];
```

?

Thank you for the reply.

Comment: I don't know fortran, what is the code supposed to do?

Comment: You can declare it in a method body, but it will only live there then. That may be good or not. If you need a  more 'global' variable declare it at class level! Look fo 'variable scope' !

Comment: @ Thank you TaW. The upper Fortran 77 code is a single dimensional array with 11 reserved spaces in it?
@Fahad, it is suppose to calculate a particular temperature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title indicates that you might be confusing `list` with `array`.  I believe you are asking how to *translate* FORTRAN arrays to C# arrays.

The FORTRAN variables you are converting are arrays, not lists.  They will always be arrays.  There are no lists in FORTRAN, unless you code them yourself.

My reading and testing indicate that C# does not support choosing your own array index lower bound.  In other words: the lower bound is always zero.  Array indexing in C# is always zero-based.  So you cannot translate the FORTRAN arrays directly unless their lower-bound is already zero.

Taking your example:

```
float[] c = new float[1:7];
```

Since the lower-bound is 1, and not zero, you must shift-down any indexing by 1.

Your example array needs to contain 7 elements, so declare it in C# as:

```
float[] c = new float[7];
```

and the addressing, or indexing, of these elements will be:

```
float[0] = 10.5f;  // the first element
float[1] = ...     // the second element
float[6] = ...     // the last element
float[7] =         // runtime error: array index out of bounds
```

So you will need to offset the index in your C# code to accommodate the shift.

P.S. I tried, as an experiment, allocating an array in C# with bounds-specifiers such as `float[1:7]` and got a compiler error indicating that it was not expecting a lower-bound.

Answer (score 5):

Here you are:

```
float[] c = new float[11];
```

The [MSDN Arrays Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx) is a helpful reference.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you Hungndv. So this is a single dimensional array after all.
What about this: ```float[] c = new float[1:7];``` How would that be translated into C#? ```float[] c = new float[8];```?

Comment: @marco: as reference here: [https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Fortran_variables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Fortran_variables). It say that `REAL               :: c(0:3) ! declare c as an array of 4 floating point numbers from c(0) to c(3)`. Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you. I took a look at that wikibooks link, and looks like ```float[] c = new float[1:7];``` would be ``an array of 4 floating point numbers from c(1) to c(7).```. But how would that be defined in C#?

Answer (score 1):

As hungndv wrote `float[] c = new float[11];` would be the correct declaration for this array.

`real acl,c(0:10)` is declaring a real variable and a real array.  In this case it's specifying an array with 11 elements that begins with 0 and ends at element 10.  By default in Fortran 77, arrays are 1-based, but they can optionally start at zero or negative numbers.  For instance:

`real d(-10:10,-100:100)` would declare a 2 dimensional array where the x-element was -10 based and the y-element was -100 based.  I always wished other languages had the ability to declare the bottom of an array, I found it quite useful when I was doing mathematical modeling.